# Sending GET request with parameters represented as object (axios,fetch)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, axios, fetch

I have such parameters. Some of them are represented as object ("variables" is object for example), so how can i send a GET request with these parameters?

```html
{"operationName":"getPostList","variables":{"input":{"type":"post","locale":"en","projectId":"1"}},"query":"query getPostList($input: PostSearchType) {\n  posts(input: $input, paging: {limit: 12}) {\n    items {\n      id\n    type\n   locale\n  shortDescription\n fullUrl\n   thumbnail\n   tags\n      title\n      publishedAt\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
```

Comment: However you like … but largely determined by how the parser on the server expects you to present nested data. The query string standard only describes key=value pairs.

Comment: the server is on Node.js, so i should just list them?

Answer (score -1):

At first I thought it's easy, just add them as body. But it turns out you can't add body to GET request. [axios github page says:](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

> `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
> Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'

You can only add params, but:

> `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request
> Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object

But there's something that may save you: paramsSerializer

> `paramsSerializer` is an optional function in charge of serializing `params`
> (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

e.g.

```
paramsSerializer: function (params) {
    return Qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'})
}
```

From now on you just need to figure out how to serialize your params- with that I can't help without knowing how the receiving system expects them to be formatted.